Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{7^nn!}{n^n}$
How can I calculate $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{7^nn!}{n^n}\ ?$$
I realize that $ n^n$ grows faster than each of the two factors in the numerator individually. So I thought the limit probably goes to zero.
However, judging by my graphing calculator, it seems this sequence diverges to infinity.

Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}>1$.

$n! \approx \sqrt{2\pi n } (n/e)^n\implies n!/n^n \approx \sqrt{2\pi n}/e^n$
